# How to specify Schema for Lists while mapping Nhibernate by code

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want my "tag_post" table to be created in "article" schema but it's created in "public" schema.

```
List(x => x.Tags, l =>
        {
            l.Where("deleted = 0");

            l.Key(k =>
            {
                k.Column("post_id");
                k.NotNullable(true);
            });
            Schema(Constants.DatabaseSchemaNames.Article);
            l.Table("tag_post");
        }, x =>
        {
            x.ManyToMany(m => m.Column("tag_id"));
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used mapping by code, but i assume this is the solution:

```
List(x => x.Students, l =>
{
    l.Where("deleted = 0");

    l.Key(k =>
    {
        k.Column("post_id");
        k.NotNullable(true);
    });
    l.Schema(Constants.DatabaseSchemaNames.Article);
    l.Table("tag_post");
}, x =>
{
    x.ManyToMany(m => m.Column("tag_id"));
});
```